# How to find a place when shopping cart price rules applied?

Tags: cart, price

I'm looking for place at code where shopping cart price rules are applied. Lets say, I've created a rule and when I add some product to shopping cart which match this rule, this rule will be applied and can change a price. I'm trying to explore module `SalesRules`, but without success. Maybe someone can give me a right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The starting point for all salesrules are in the Observer:

```
\Mage_SalesRule_Model_Observer::sales_quote_address_discount_item()
```

There `\Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator::process()` is called, where it is checked whether the rule should be applied:

```
if (!$this->_canProcessRule($rule, $address)) {
    continue;
}

if (!$rule->getActions()->validate($item)) {
    continue;
}
```

and afterwards the discounts are applied.

I hope this helps you on your way into the salesrules.

Comment: I am confused in your answer what should i write in my observer?i just want to check one flag from quote and if it is false then i don't want to apply rule.How can i achive this using observer?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question. To get the quote you can call `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/quote')` and check for the flag.

Comment: I know that i can get quote flag like that but here i m asking that when my flag is false then i would like to stop applie rule on that quote.

For that what should i do

Comment: Please mention the file path